# Update XML template file with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink

I've created XML file Let's call it template.xml. It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <head>
    <title>TITLE</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <section/>
         <section>
            <p>section1</p>
         </section>
         <section>
            <p>section2</p>
         </section>
         <table/>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now I' d like tu unmarshall template.xml and change only content of specyfic tags.

What i am trying to do is to use JAXB mashaller in similar way as XSL. I'd like to have my template file and then change only specyfic tags. I've tried to create models with EclipseLink XMLPath

```
package html.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="html")
public class Html {


    @XmlPath("body/div")
    private Div div;

    public Div getDiv() {
        return div;
    }

    public void setDiv(Div div) {
        this.div = div;
    } 



}
```

My program looks like this:

```
public class Updater {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            File file = new File("html_example.xml");
            JAXBContext jc =  JAXBContext.newInstance(Html.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            Html html = (Html) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            Div div = html.getDiv();
            Section section = div.getSection();
            section.setName("UPDATED VALUE");


            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(html, new File("html_example.xml"));


        } catch (JAXBException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

But my output is then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <body>
      <div>
         <section>
            <p>Jemmy_test</p>
         </section>
         <section>
            <p>UPDATED VALUE</p>
         </section>
         <table/>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

So in this example I'm loosing head tags.
Is there any way to make marshaller work a little bit smarter?

Comment: So if you unmarshall this file then marshall the object again straight away it removes all your values? It sounds like you're not unmarshalling the XML file correctly.

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you've not mapped the head elements to anything so when you unmarashall the xml it just discards it. Marshalling your object creates a new file that has no idea about  elements.

You would need to model all the elements in the xml if you want them all outputted again. You could generate all the models from the xhtml schema though which would do a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Yes,  I know that if I create model with all tags it will work. The thing is that I do not want to this. In my template there will be a lot of different tags, also with static text inside them. It will be much more convinient and readable for me to create models that access to only specyfic tags.